# Setting a CSS Value from a PHP Variable

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, session

I want to apply the following CSS entry to a website:

```
background-image: url(http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/mainsiteimage/datingbali.co.jpg);
```

the catch is I have a few of these sites and I need to use a variable like follows:

```
http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/mainsiteimage/<?php echo $_SESSION['domain'];?>.jpg
```

This is being applied to the `<body>` tag (adding a background image to the front page) - will remove for other pages.

Anyone have any ideas on the way to set this CSS entry with a PHP `$_SESSION` variable?

Note: I'm very comfortable using JQUERY so a solution with this would be great...

Comment: Is the CSS internal or external? If it's internal, just do what you did. If it's external, you're going to need to tell Apache or PHP (I forget which) to scan .css for php. Look up how to put PHP in JavaScript files, and just replace for css.

Comment: I need to ask, is this PHP variable coming from another page or the same page? If it is coming from another page, you need to communicate that variable with AJAX. Otherwise you should be able to simply insert it into your document with PHP where you need it.

Comment: Found a tutorial. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/

Comment: :) thankyou so much for all the advice... I'll look at the page... its external CSS... I will try the PHP set inline styles... great ideas... this site is so good..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place style rules anywhere in the head or body section of the document. So you could use an inline CSS section like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['domain'])) : ?>
    <style>
        body {
            http://www.datingimages.co/online-dating/dating-website/mainsiteimage/<?php echo $_SESSION['domain'];?>.jpg
        }
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks very much... works really well... didn't know you could do this but after seeing it, it makes logical sense... thx again...!!

Answer (score 2):

Use inline CSS if you don't want to resort to more complex processing methods or JavaScript. In my opinion, you shouldn't have to use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well after the page loads you can restyle it by making an ajax request and switching the element.

i.e

```
 $(function() {
    $.get('ajax.php', ..., function(data) {
        $('#element').css('background-image', data.url);
    });
 });
```

or something of that sort, but I don't like this idea ... seems too much like a monkey patch.

You could have perhaps predefined css's for each `$_SESSION` and load them when the page loads, but that means you'll have to break your css into smaller files, I think that would be a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

When the user logs in, say you have 3 background image choices. You pull the user's background preference from your database, or whatever system you have. Maybe bob gets a blue background, and everyone else gets a green one. Then you store that in the $_SESSION for the user. For example:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['username'] == 'bob') {
        $_SESSION['bodybg'] == "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/blue_background_abstract-wide.jpg"
    } else {
        $_SESSION['bodybg'] == "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zx4w4PCEgEY/ULv64dBGGnI/AAAAAAAAA6Y/SRcHkfMBiJs/s1600/C4D_Green_background__by_Darkchildh.jpg"
    }
?>
```

Then when generating the page, or the css for the page, you put it in. I'll give the css as an example:

```
body {
    background: url('<?php echo $_SESSION['bodybg']; ?>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your architecture if you face such problem. Better to load different html wrappers based on your session value.